# gridview column item style is not working

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am populating a grid view from DB using vb.net problem is that after binding the gridview i changed the item stlye but it gives the this error

`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection`

Here is My Code

```
Public Sub loadnews()
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT A.LABEL ""Highest"",A.VALUE||' '||A.DATED ""SML I (Jhang)"",b.VALUE||' '||b.DATED ""SML II (Bhone)"" FROM (SELECT * FROM CMS20122013.DNEWS_HIGHEST_J@CMS) A, (SELECT * FROM CMS20122013.DNEWS_HIGHEST_B@CMS) B WHERE A.SRLNUM=B.SRLNUM", con)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            GridView11.DataSource = ds
            GridView11.DataBind()
            GridView11.Columns(1).ItemStyle.Font.Bold = True
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Please Any one Help how Can I make bold the `0` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
      For i = 0 To GridView11.Rows.Count - 1
    GridView11.Rows(i).Cells(0).Font.Bold = True
      Next
```

Comment: use this answer wihtout ItemStyle

Comment: this made bold only fist item.cani make bold whole column?

Comment: you have to use loop for this that make it

Comment: This Made To Column Bold With Also Showing a Exception of Same Error as I wrote in My Question

Answer (score 0):

**Use RowDataBound event:**

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      e.Row.Cells(0).Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```